# Googlebot and FAMUOS $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']

Tags: googlebot

I did `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` on my site, where have two langs PL and EN.

I really didn't suspect Google would reindex my site (meaning TITLE and DESC) from PL to EN that way.

Shouldnt it use PL since it is crawling Polish domains, hmmmmrrrr cant understand ?

Anyway i can detect googlebot and set them PL again

But it wouldnt be cloacking or smthing ?

Anyone could tell me what would be good solution to get it straight so, me and Google would be happy ?

Answer (score 1):

the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE means the language that the CLIENT (the client browser,in this case the crawler)supports and it's an information the client send with the request(like the ip,etc.),it's not something the server sends to the client.
To tell the client what languages your website supports you must use the meta tags,in your case for example

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pl, en" />
```

will tell the client that you site prefer PL language but support ENG.

This is  [the w3c page about it](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-html-lan)

Comment: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE it was used for language recognision.

If I set meta to (pl, en) nothing will change...

This meta tag tells browser that my site uses two languages, but for what purpose, where it can be used ?

If someone got EN as default in their browser and i got meta (pl, en) on my site,
site still will be shown to him in pl, so really what for this meta lang is for ?.

With HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE i can determine and change website lang for client.

My only problem is that, bots olso use EN.